# Log the number of change detections in Angular (Globally)

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to see how many change detection cycles are running in my app ( *and who initiated it*)  - which has many many components.

Currently  , I know that  , at each component  , I can use  the `ngDoCheck` method :

- `ngDoCheck()`

> Detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its
>   own. Called during every change detection run, immediately after
>   ngOnChanges() and ngOnInit().

This is not a bad solution.

**Question:**

But - is there a way to do it *globally* ? I mean  , I really don't want to modify each component and add this code.

Is there a way that the "listener & Logger" will be in a global scope so that i'll know  which part of my app causes many change detection cycles?

My goal (if possible) :

```
(console.log) -- from component A
(console.log) -- from component A
(console.log) -- from component A

(console.log) -- from component B

(console.log) -- from component C
(console.log) -- from component C
```

Comment: probably NgZone.run(callback)

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka This code runs a code in the zone. it's not a global callback handler which attached to detection cycle.

Comment: https://ng-run.com/edit/DKfJ7hnnDsDnK4riV4UK?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts All valuable code is in main.ts

Comment: @yurzui Exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.  ❤

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AfterViewChecked` should help you:

> Respond after Angular checks the component's views and child views / the view that a directive is in.
>   Called after the ngAfterViewInit and every subsequent ngAfterContentChecked().

If you implement `AfterViewChecked` in your `AppComponent`, it should fire every time any change happens in any of the child components:

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
    console.trace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way to extract the "initiator" name ?

Comment: I'm afraid that for that you'll actually need to touch every individual component